# how to change color of text based on value?

Tags: colors, cat, numeric-data

I want to use cat to display a file content and changes the text color to red if the number is larger than 50.

Example:

> cat file1

would give

> 1 33 56

the number 56 will be displayed in red color in the terminal

Comment: Please update your question and explain what you've tried so far and how what you've tried doesn't do what you want?

Comment: check the color coding from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Answer (score 2):

Can we use `grep`:

```
echo 1 33 56 | grep --color -E '[5-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]+'
```